# Factor an integer to something as close to a square as possible

Tags: python, algorithm, cython, factoring

I have a function that reads a file byte by byte and converts it to a floating point array. It also returns the number of elements in said array.
Now I want to reshape the array into a 2D array with the shape being as close to a square as possible.

As an example let's look at the number 800:

`sqrt(800) = 28.427...`

Now by I can figure out by trial and error that `25*32` would be the solution I am looking for. 
I do this by decrementing the `sqrt` (rounded to nearest integer) if the result of multiplying the integers is to high, or incrementing them if the result is too low.

I know about algorithms that do this for primes, but this is not a requirement for me. My problem is that even the brute force method I implemented will sometimes get stuck and never finish (which is the reason for my arbitrary limit of iterations):

```
import math

def factor_int(n):
    nsqrt = math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))

    factors = [nsqrt, nsqrt]
    cd = 0
    result = factors[0] * factors[1]
    ii = 0
    while (result != n or ii > 10000):
        if(result > n):
            factors[cd] -= 1
        else:
            factors[cd] += 1
        result = factors[0] * factors[1]
        print factors, result
        cd = 1 - cd
        ii += 1

    return "resulting factors: {0}".format(factors)

input = 80000
factors = factor_int(input)
```

using this script above the output will get stuck in a loop printing

```
[273.0, 292.0] 79716.0
[273.0, 293.0] 79989.0
[274.0, 293.0] 80282.0
[274.0, 292.0] 80008.0
[273.0, 292.0] 79716.0
[273.0, 293.0] 79989.0
[274.0, 293.0] 80282.0
[274.0, 292.0] 80008.0
[273.0, 292.0] 79716.0
[273.0, 293.0] 79989.0
[274.0, 293.0] 80282.0
[274.0, 292.0] 80008.0
[273.0, 292.0] 79716.0
[273.0, 293.0] 79989.0
[274.0, 293.0] 80282.0
[274.0, 292.0] 80008.0
[273.0, 292.0] 79716.0
[273.0, 293.0] 79989.0
[274.0, 293.0] 80282.0
```

But I wonder if there are more efficient solutions for this? Certainly I can't be the first to want to do something like this.

Comment: What if n is a prime. Must it go all the way to n*1 as your factors?

Comment: in this case, yes if it does not find two primes before that by chance. I assume that the data I read can always be represented by a rectangle, though. Also now that I think about it, it will probably get stuck then, too.. I change the factor that is incremented or decremented on every other iteration...

Comment: I just discussed this question at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2016/08/23/nearly-square-divisors-revisited/), and readers gave some ridiculously good solutions, much better than mine, in the comments. Go have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def factor_int(n):
    val = math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))
    val2 = int(n/val)
    while val2 * val != float(n):
        val -= 1
        val2 = int(n/val)
    return val, val2, n
```

try it with:

```
for x in xrange(10, 20):
      print factor_int(x)
```

Comment: wow that was fast. I feel dumb now, that I did not think about the `n/val` ... :D

Comment: Cool, there are probably much better ways as well.

Comment: well I was not looking for a perfect solution, just for a quick one ! :)

Comment: Thanks. This is a "most excellent" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
import math


def min_dist(a, b):
    dist = []
    for Pa in a:
        for Pb in b:
            d = math.sqrt(
                math.pow(Pa[0] - Pb[0], 2) + math.pow(Pa[1] - Pb[1], 2))
            dist.append([d, Pa])

    return sorted(dist, key=lambda x: x[0])


def get_factors(N):
    if N < 1:
        return N

    N2 = N / 2
    NN = math.sqrt(N)

    result = []
    for a in range(1, N2 + 1):
        for b in range(1, N2 + 1):
            if N == (a * b):
                result.append([a, b])

    result = min_dist(result, [[NN, NN]])
    if result:
        return result[0][1]
    else:
        return [N, 1]


for i in range(801):
    print i, get_factors(i)
```

The key of this method is finding the minimum distance to the cartesian point of [math.sqrt(N), math.sqrt(N)] which meets the requirements N=a*b, a&b integers.

Comment: I like your answer, because your approach has the mathematics behind the problem  :) 
I compared the results to the results of the answer I accepted and they both give the same results (at least for integers between 1 and 100000)

Comment: @meetaig I'm sure my solution can be optimized further (right now is brute-force) but at least gives the insights to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the modulus operator is a good fit for this problem:

```
import math 

def factint(n):
    pos_n = abs(n)
    max_candidate = int(math.sqrt(pos_n))
    for candidate in xrange(max_candidate, 0, -1):
        if pos_n % candidate == 0:
            break
    return candidate, n / candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct method that finds the smallest, closest integers `a`, `b`, such that `a * b >= n`, and `a <= b`, where `n` is any number:

```
def factor_int(n):
    a = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    b = math.ceil(n/float(a))
    return a, b
```

try it with:

```
for x in xrange(10, 20):
    print factor_int(x)
```

Comment: The question is asking for `a * b == n`, not `a * b >= n`.

Comment: This is create for a tile scheme (rows/colums) in UI with variable amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter code based on the currently accepted answer that is shorter and takes about 25%-75% less time to run than their code (from basic timeit tests):

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
def factor_int_2(n):
    val = ceil(sqrt(n))
    while True:
        if not n%val:
            val2 = n//val
            break
        val -= 1
return val, val2
```

And here's a small and messy test I made to test the efficiency of the method:

```
print("Method 2 is shorter and about {}% quicker".format(100*(1 - timeit(lambda: factor_int_2(12345))/timeit(lambda: factor_int(12345)))))
#returns 'Method 2 is shorter and about 75.03810670186826% quicker'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneline code for one number:

```
import numpy as np
n = 800
(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)), np.ceil(n/np.ceil(np.sqrt(n))))
```

---

```
>>> (29.0, 28.0)
```

Not sure if it is what you asked for, but this is much closer to square than (25,32) as you mentioned in the description. Hope it helps!

Comment: it's closer to a square, but 29*28 is not 800...

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to finding factors `(b,c)` for `a=b*c` such that the smaller factor, `b`, is the largest number not larger than `sqrt(a)`. This can be solved by:

```
import math

def closest_factors(a):
    for b in range(int(math.sqrt(a)), 0, -1):
        if a%b == 0:
            c = a // b
            return (b,c)

 print(closest_factors(800))
```

returns (25,32).